# automatically generating .h from .cpp/.c

Tags: automation, header-files

Is there a command line tool to automatically generate a .h from its .cpp or .c?

It seems like a very obvious thing to do, I don't know why it never dawned on me before now...

Of course, in the .h there should be more things than just function prototypes, so the tool could be non-trivial. Or could be trivial, requiring you to include two .h: the generated one and the custom one.

Anyway, I'd rather avoid reinventing the wheel, that's why I'm asking if it already exists.

Comment: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/ did you try googling this? :-)

Comment: the classic SO rhetoric question :)

Comment: @LiorCohen: I tried to think of a query to find it, but I didn't manage to... now that you point it out I admit I could've tried harder.

Comment: @LiorCohen: that said, could you post it as an answer?

Comment: +1 - While creating a program to create AI-based programs has crossed my mind, this has not. Very useful if you know exactly what you want to do rather than base projects off of the headers.

Comment: @Lohoris: posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/